# (when) is a map of schemes determines by values on Zariski dense subset?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The motivation for this question is to justify/understand a particular abuse of notation in the world of group schemes, namely people write things like $m:(g_1,g_2) \mapsto g_1g_2$ when discussing the multiplication or action maps $G \times_k G \to G$ when $G$ is a group scheme over $k$. This bothers me because over a general base field $k$, identifying points in the fibered product $G \times_k G$ as pairs $(g_1,g_2)$ only makes sense on $k$-rational points.

However, suppose we are in the situation where the $G(k) \hookrightarrow G$ is Zariski dense, and $G$ is a variety, so in particular (geometrically) reduced, separated, etc. Then I would think that a map on $k$-rational points, given by polynomials, determines uniquely a map of schemes.

So the question is, suppose $X$ is a variety of a general base field $k$ such that $X(k)$ is Zariski dense in $X$. Then does a regular map $X(k) \to Y$, $Y$ separated, determine uniquely a morphism $X \to Y$.

Comment: The general way this abuse of notation is justified if the following theorem: Let $G$ be a scheme, and $F_G$ the functor from schemes to sets represented by $G$. Then $G$ is a group scheme if and only if $F_G$ is group valued.

Comment: Hence we may use this to get an actually group with elements, which is nice.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the functor of points definition. My question in that context, I suppose, would be to what extent do polynomial maps $G(k) \to H(k)$ determine morphisms $G \to H$

Comment: What do you mean in general by a polynomial map $G(k) \rightarrow H(k)$?  It's clear what this means in the affine case

Comment: I guess I should say regular map, in the sense of the theory of algebraic variety as (glued from) closed subsets of $k^n$, although affine case is enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are geometrically reduced, separated, finite type $k$-schemes with $X(k)$ dense in $X$, then yes, all of these things are the same:

- "Regular maps" $X(k) \rightarrow Y(k)$ (nonstandard terminology to define such things on $k$-rational points when $k$ is not algebraically closed, but w/e)
- Regular maps of classical varieties $X(\overline{k}) \rightarrow Y(\overline{k})$ which are "defined over $k$" in the sense that affine locally, they are polynomial functions defined via polynomials with coefficients in $k$
- Morphisms of $k$-schemes $X \rightarrow Y$

When your schemes are not geometrically reduced, you have to be careful because a regular map $X(\overline{k}) \rightarrow Y(\overline{k})$ might not give you a morphism of schemes.  This is because $X(\overline{k})$ is the classical variety associated to the scheme $X_{\textrm{red}}$.

When I'm dealing with group schemes $G, H$ of finite type over a field $k$, with $k$ is perfect, and I want to define a morphism of group schemes $f: G \rightarrow H$, I usually go the "classical" route of considering the map on $\overline{k}$ points $G(\overline{k}) \rightarrow H(\overline{k})$.  I check that this is a regular map and a group homomorphism.  Then I check whether it is "defined over $k$" by checking that it commutes with the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ on $G(\overline{k})$ and $H(\overline{k})$.  That ensures everything coming from a unique morphism of group schemes $G \rightarrow H$.